# unable to compile class for jsp (Tomcat version 6)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have imported the code form the repository and ran the code. Everything worked fine. I just added a new JSP from then i am getting an error.

Please find the attchemnt for the error.[image]

I am using tomcat version 6 and java 6. Don't know if its a config problem.But in jsp i just added form .So if anyone has an idea of why the issue is happening here please help me out :) Thanks in advance.

JSP:

```
<form:form action="/saveUser" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uName" value=""/>
<input type="password" name="pwd" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Kindly try adding the code changes which introduced the error if Possible

Comment: Its just a simple form. I have added the jsp. thanks @Mr.Arjun

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring form tag, add this on top of JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

or use simple HTML form like

```
<form action="/action">
    <!-- your code -->
</form>
```